# How to know if NAs come from the same observations in R

Tags: r, na

Q1) I have 3 variables with very close number of missing values.
How can I see how much of the observations have those 3 variables as missing? ie how many of the observations have these 3 variables missing?

Q2) And if results show that a considerable number have those 3 missing together, is there a specific way to deal with them?

Comment: We need you to post us an example snippet, just use some seeded-random data. Say you have columns `col1, col2, col3...` where those columns have lots of NAs. You could calculate which rows (indexes) have all three f those columns NA. See the existing solutions on SO for that.

Comment: Then when you say *"is there a specific way to deal with them?"*, sounds like you want to do imputation on the missing values, but you're not telling us about their types or ranges. Are they integer (e.g. age), numerical (e.g. height, income) or categorical (e.g. marital status, zipcode etc.). Would we expect that the distribution of col1 (say, height) should affect the distribution of col2? If it was, say, weight, then yes, but if it was method person commutes to work, then no. (Read about the concepts MAR, MCAR, MNAR). Not enough information. Please post sample data. Even made-up data is ok.

Comment: See [tag:imputation], MAR, MNAR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to calculate the number of rows with NA values for all three columns:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.table(var1 = c(1, 2, 3, NA, NA), var2 = c(NA, 2, NA, NA, NA), var3 = c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA))

total_na_rows <- df %>%
  filter(is.na(var1) & is.na(var2) & is.na(var3)) %>%
  summarise(na_rows = n())

total_na_rows
# na_rows
# 1       2
```